# WaitForNonStaleResults per DocumentStore

Tags: .net, nosql, ravendb

Is there any way to tell RavenDb to use WaitForNonStaleResults mode for all queries of some DocumentStore or DocumentSession?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `DefaultQueryingConsistency = ConsistencyOptions.QueryYourWrites` at the DocumentStore or Session level.

**DocumentStore:**

```cs
IDocumentStore store = new DocumentStore {
    Url = "http://127.0.0.1:8080",
    DefaultDatabase = "DBNAME",
    Conventions = {
        DefaultQueryingConsistency = ConsistencyOptions.QueryYourWrites
    }
}.Initialize();
```

**Session:**

```cs
session.Advanced.Conventions.DefaultQueryingConsistency = 
    ConsistencyOptions.QueryYourWrites;
```

**Bear in mind that this mechanism does not work for Map-Reduce Indexes**

You can check [Matt's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4500/matt-warren) comments on this matter below

Comment: One thing to note, QueryYourWrites doesn't work with Map/Reduce indexes. For these you have to use WaitForNonStaleResults..()

Comment: Matt Warren, what do you mean? I thought all indexes in RavenDb are map-reduce indexes...

Comment: @Idsa hopefully I've cleared this up in my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/8573878/4500